# How to delete Facebook app requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am trying to delete pending app requests after entering my canvas application.  I followed the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting to issue an HTTP DELETE request to the URI mentioned in the documentation, using the request ID for a request from my app (accessed from the Graph API) as well as the user access token.  I only get an error that says, "Some of the aliases you requested do not exist."  I suspect there is an issue with my way of formatting this URI.  Here's what I did, using Ruby on Rails and HTTParty:

```
 HTTParty.delete("https://graph.facebook.com/#{outstanding_app_request_ids}?access_token=[#{session[:access_token]}]")
```

Does anyone have an example of a URI that successfully deletes these requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a much more elegant solution that uses the Koala gem, and deletes the outstanding app requests in one swoop with a batch request.  Here is the code that gets the requests, as well as deletes them all at once.

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(ACCESS_TOKEN)
raw_requests = @graph.get_connections("me", "apprequests")
app_request_ids = []
raw_requests.each do |request|
  app_request_ids << request["id"]
end
if app_request_ids.size > 0
  @graph.batch do |batch_api|
    app_request_ids.each do |app_request_id|
      batch_api.delete_object(app_request_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Tim White's solution is better

Comment: @Calin, Why do you think it's better?

Comment: Perhaps people think that this is also serial? The Koala Batch api takes requests.each, and then batch processes on 'end'. Ref. https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Batch-requests

Answer (score 3):

Using Koala is easiest in Ruby in my opinion:

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook.API.new(ACCESS_TOKEN) #Get access to graph
app_requests = @graph.get_connections(UID, 'apprequests') #Get app_requests

app_requests.collect {|request| request['id']}.each do |id|
   @graph.delete_object(id) # Delete app_request
end
```

Comment: The only issue here is that the requests are deleted one-by-one.  It's better to delete them all at once with a batch request.  See the selected answer to this question.

Comment: delete_object(request.id)  should be delete_object(id)

Answer (score 1):

Open this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{outstandingapprequestids}_{userid}?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=DELETE
```

Comment: With that, I can't seem to get the '{' and '}' to format correctly.  They are not allowed raw, and using the percent-encoding codes includes unwanted '/'.  I tried replacing them with '[' as per Facebook's documentation, and I still get the 803, aliases do not exist error.

Comment: This is not needed to be in url : {}here is an example
`https://graph.facebook.com/REQUEST ID_userid?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=DELETE`
For example`https://graph.facebook.com/123456789_1000002342?access_token=A0000A05420&method=DELETE`

Comment: Thanks, this is working from my browser.  Now, I just need to do from my rails app.  HTTParty isn't working the way I need it to.

Comment: i'm a php programer There is function called file_get_contents($url) which it loads the $url There must be something like that in rail anyway Just forget to issue HTTP DELETE &methode=DELETE is doing exactly that just write a code to open the link (with &methode=DELETE)

Comment: Finally working.  Thanks again, here's the final thing that worked:  `open("https://graph.facebook.com/REQUESTID_USERID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&method=DELETE")`.  The next step is deleting multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: deleting multiple requests at same time is so easy 
Just get all of them from me/apprequests & remove them one by one :)
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fapprequests